# Python3 not set as default on AWS EC2 linux

Tags: python-3.x

I have installed Python38 on aws EC2 linux, and set it as default by running sudo alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.8, but still not working. Python2.7 still the default.

Answer (score 0):

Python is preinstalled on Linux as python 2.7. To run python 3 use the command `python3 script.py`. This calls upon the python 3 interpreter while `python script.py` calls upon the python 2.7 interpreter.

Comment: how to set python3 as default? creating alias temp work, but other things does not work like installing pip3